# Как изменить шаблоны в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio, intellij-idea

Когда я пишу код то бывает что мне нужно добавить try catch, но так как по умолчанию шаблон мне не нравиться он делает код не читабельным, я хочу его изменить под себя. Какой пунтк в настройках отвечает за данную фишку?

Вот допустим

```
try{
catch()
{
}
}
```

А я хочу чтобы было так

```
try{
catch() { }
}
```

Comment: Речь идет о *Live Templates* - сокращениях для ввода блоков кода или о каких шаблонах идет речь ?

Comment: Нет, потому что я там искал catch но там его не было.

Вот вы когда код пишете. Потом строка красной строкой обводиться после нажатия на эту строку появится меню с выбором добавиления try catch, так как данный метод содержит Exeption

Comment: @pavlofff, щя скрин скину короч

Comment: Эти неизвестно где находятся, возможно они вообще не в отдельном файле, пригодном для редактирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идет о стартовых шаблонах проекта, таких как: *Blanck Activity*, *LoginActivity*, *MasterDetailFlow* и тд. то из настроек *Android Studio* их не изменить.

Вы можете проследовать по пути (сам каталог Android Studio может находится и не в корне диска С, а там, куда вы его установили - по умолчанию в папке пользователя):

`C:\AndroidStudio\plugins\android\lib\templates\`

Здесь вы увидите папки со всеми стартовыми шаблонами студии. Файлы кода шаблонов хранятся в формате .ftl , но он открывается любым тестовым редактором, например `Notepad++` и доступен для редактирования. Сам код шаблона содержится в подпапке `/root/src/`

**ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ**: После редактирования стартовых шаблонов не проходит апдейт IDE через обновление. Появляется предупреждение, что файлы (в которых были внесены изменения) не соответствуют и апдейт отменяется.
Решил проблему установив поверх последний релиз.

Comment: скрин добавил вв

Comment: Вот как эти стандартные шаблоны изменять?
Try catch